# Why is the thumbnail size different between Firefox and Mozilla when using filepicker_image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filepicker.io

I have the following code in my view file:

```
 <%= filepicker_image_tag tool.img_url, w: 160, h: 160, fit: 'clip'%>
```

When using Mozilla Firefox, the thumbnails show up correctly.  When using Safari, the thumbnails show up really small.  Any ideas why?

Comment: What's the resulting HTML look like?

Comment: @Deefour In Firefox and Safari, the resulting HTML is: `<img height="160" src="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/O9jfCmwRKy6xyyMVtq3z/convert?fit=clip&amp;h=160&amp;w=160" width="160" />`

Comment: **http://jsfiddle.net/u6vMy/** Looks the same to me in FF and Safari. You might want to make sure your HTML is valid (not for the filepicker image, but for the full page's source.)

Comment: @Deefour, thanks for helping out.  How do I make sure HTML is valid for the page source?